# How to implement like query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to make a query with multiple conditions but the `like` query is not working:

```
 exports.getAllPeoduct = async (req, res) => {
        var where = [];

        if(Common.required(req.query.shopId)) where.push({shopId : req.query.shopId});
        if(Common.required(req.query.categoryId)) where.push({categoryId : req.query.categoryId});
        if(Common.required(req.query.price)) where.push({price : req.query.price});
        if(Common.required(req.query.color)) where.push({availableColors :'/.*'+req.query.color+'.*/'});

        console.log(where);

        // if(Common.required(req.query.size)) where.availableSizes = req.query.size;

        try{
            // if(Common.required(shopId)) {

                let getAllProduct = await product.find({$or : where});

                if(getAllProduct.length){
                    Common.sendResponseBack(res, 200,message.OK ,message.getAllProductMessage, getAllProduct);
                } else {
                    Common.sendResponseBack(res, 200, message.OK, message.NoRecordFoundMessage, getAllProduct);
                }
            // } else {
            //  Common.sendResponseBack(res, 403,message.FAIL, message.passAllReqFields, null);
            // }
        } catch (err){
            logger.error( 'Error occured on '+new Date()+' with reason' + err);
            Common.sendResponseBack(res, 403, message.FAIL, message.internalErrorMsg, null);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i did not get any error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
availableColors : new Regex('/.*'+req.query.color+'.*/')
```